# Recall approval process by community users

Tags: community, approval-process

I have setup an approval process which will be triggered by Process builder based on a field which will be changed by Community user.Approval process is for address update done by community user.I am able to submit contact record for an approval process. However, I also want to recall approval process based on a field which will be changed by community users.

```
   public static boolean recallApprovalProcess(String contactId){
       ProcessInstance instance = [SELECT Id
                                    FROM   ProcessInstance
                                    WHERE TargetObjectId=:contactId AND Status='Pending' limit 1];
```

```
    // Now that we have our Approval Request instance, lets get the child WorkItem
    ProcessInstanceWorkitem workItem = [SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
                                        where ProcessInstanceId=:instance.Id limit 1]; 
    Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest();
    req.setWorkItemId(workItem.Id);
    req.setAction('Removed'); // This means to remove/recall Approval Request
    req.setComments('Customer withdrawn approval process.');

    Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req); 

   /* Contact con =[select approval_stage__c from contact where id=:contactId];
    con.Approval_Stage__c ='Not Started';
    update con; */
   return result.isSuccess();
}
```

However, I am getting below exception:

```
04:41:07.0 (27574593)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:ApprovalProcessActions
04:41:07.0 (27855734)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:ApprovalProcessActions
04:41:07.0 (28163842)|DML_END|[1081]
04:41:07.0 (28281654)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[1081]|System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []
04:41:07.0 (28736590)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[1081]|Bytes:158
04:41:07.0 (28769940)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|true
04:41:07.0 (29395951)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Class.classname.recallApprovalProcess: line 1081, column 1
04:41:07.0 (29416225)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Class.classname.recallApprovalProcess: line 1081, column 1
```

Comment: In the approval process, have you enabled 'Allow Submitters to Recall Approval Requests'? Also, I think it should be setAction('Remove') [Not removed; although SOAP API developer guide mentions it as 'Removed']

Comment: 'Allow Submitters to Recall Approval Requests' is checked in approval process. Although the Submitter is System admin for every approval  since process builder is being used to trigger approval process. Initial submitter in process builder is set to system admin because we can't individual add community user as initial submitter in approval process.